# Why is there variation in helicopter autorotation maneuvers?

Tags: helicopter, auto-rotation

Why are there some different autorotation techniques?

For example, on light helicopters, like the [Airbus Helicopters H125](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurocopter_AS350_%C3%89cureuil) or [Aérospatiale Gazelle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%A9rospatiale_Gazelle), you do not flare too much: at 70-100ft AGL adjust some nose up attitude, and keep it almost constant until the touchdown, and cushion the touchdown with collective.

But on bigger helicopters, you have a lot of nose up on the beginning of the flare (up to 20-25 degrees nose up attitude),  and then the cyclic is moved forward to place the helicopter in the level fuselage attitude for landing, and then you use collective to cushion the touchdown.

Comment: Do you have a source that says the H125 and Gazelle need substantially less than a 20deg flare?

Comment: Yes, I have manuals